# mysql category tree search

Tags: mysql, indexing, tree, sql-like, varchar

I have the following schema on MySQL 5.1

```
CREATE TABLE  `mytest` (
  `category` varchar(32) ,
  `item_name` varchar(255)
  KEY `key1` (`category`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

category column is filled with like that

```
[:parent_parent_cat_id][:parent_cat_id][:leaf_cat_id]

10000200003000
```

if you can search all of the under categories :parent_parent_category_id

```
SELECT * FROM mytest WHERE category LIKE "10000%";
```

it's using index key1;

but
How to use index when I wanna search :parent_cat_id?

```
SELECT * FROM mytest WHERE category LIKE "%20000%";
```

Do you have a better solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This model is called `materialized path`.

You just need to `categories` in a separate table and make `items` reference that table instead, not the path:

```
SELECT  i.*
FROM    categories c
JOIN    items i
ON      i.category = c.id
WHERE   c.path BETWEEN
        (
        SELECT  path
        FROM    categories ci
        WHERE   ci.id = '20000'
        )
        AND
        CONCAT(
        (
        SELECT  path
        FROM    categories ci
        WHERE   ci.id = '20000'
        ), ':')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. item.path such as '/Path/To/Leaf'  is OK? 'To''s id = '20000'

Comment: @ffff: it would be not `item.path` but `category.path`. Yes, the form is `OK`.

Comment: category.path BETWEEN '/Path/To' AND '/Path/To.' ? I need to learn more SQL Skill ...

Comment: @ffff: actually, you always need to provide a trailing separator (to distinguish between `1` and `10`), and it's better to use a separator that goes after the digits in `ASCII` order. So that would be `category.path BETWEEN 'Path:To:' AND 'Path:To::'`.

Comment: OK Maybe I got it withought BETWEEN behavior :-)

Answer (score 2):

The second query cannot use an index.

You didn't make it clear in your question whether you are able to make changes to the schema, but you should try to change it if at all possible. To store heirarchical data in MySQL I suggest you first look at the presentation [Models for hierarchical data](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data)
 by [Bill Karwin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20860/bill-karwin).

You may also want to read the series [Hierarchical queries in MySQL](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/) by [Quassnoi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55159/quassnoi).

Comment: I think index is created based on column, does not matter whatever value you are making in where caluse

Comment: @Shakti Singh: Yes, that is true in *almost* all cases. One exception is LIKE which can only use the index if the start of the string is constant (not a wildcard).

Comment: Thank you so much . but I can't get it because of my poor brain :-<